Shift + Tab tooltips not showing in JupyterLab 4.2.0 / Python 3.12.3 (pyenv) on Ubuntu 24
SHIFT + TAB tooltips are not showing for me in my fresh Jupyterlab install.
Platform: Python 3.12.3 (via pyenv) on Ubuntu 24.04.
Here's the output of $ jupyter --version:
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.24.0
ipykernel        : 6.29.4
ipywidgets       : not installed
jupyter_client   : 8.6.1
jupyter_core     : 5.7.2
jupyter_server   : 2.14.0
jupyterlab       : 4.2.0
nbclient         : 0.10.0
nbconvert        : 7.16.4
nbformat         : 5.10.4
notebook         : not installed
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.14.3


I have already imported the module I want to get tooltips for, so that's not the issue here.

Also, I don't want to get tooltips from within some convoluted expression (e.g. asking for a tooltip from requests.get(url) doesn't work).

I tried two different browsers, no luck.

I also tried uninstalling jedi as suggested here, no luck.

I also have Jupyterlab in my Python 3.8 (also pyenv) and SHIFT + TAB works fine there.


Any ideas what else to try?
NOTE: There are a bunch of questions (one, two, three) asking more or less the same, but none of them have answers that work for me & all are missing version / platform info, which is probably relevant.

Note, that this issue has been reported, see krassowski's comment here that links to a filed issue here.

OK, so I did pip install notebook, which downgraded jupyterlab from 4.2.0 to 4.1.8, and now tooltips are working.
NOTE: this appears to be a bug.

This was fixed in JupyterLab 4.2.1 which was released on 2024-05-03. The solution is to upgrade JupyterLab.

Has the functionality to open more and more verbose docs with the tab key been deprecated? eg. shift-tab-tab-tab-tab would pin the docstrings to the bottom of the page.

No, it was not deprecated. It was just never implemented in JupyterLab. Re-implementing these in Notebook 7 is tracked in https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/7034 and https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6692
